# Nested output with related models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Category and a model Weblink. Category has_many Weblink and Weblink belongs_to Category. Now I want to show all categories in a view and within a category all weblinks belonging to that category, something link this:

```
 <ul>
```

<% @categories.each do |category| %>

<%= category.category_name %>

<% @weblinks.each do |weblink| %>

<%= weblink.category_name link_to weblink.link_name, weblink.link_url %>

<% end %>
  <% end %>

In the controller I have:

```
   @categories = Category.all
```

@weblinks = Weblink.all
This shows every category and within every category all weblinks, instead of just the ones which belong to the specific category. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view code should look like this

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
   <%= category.name >
   <% category.weblinks.each do |weblink| %>
      <%= link_to weblink.name, weblink.link_url %>
   <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

It your controller, when querying for all the categories you should also include the weblinks model, something like this:

```
@categories = Category.all(:include => :weblinks)
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope the inner loop to the outer category using the macro you get with has_many:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= category.category_name %>
  <% category.weblinks.each do |weblink| %>
    <%= link_to weblink.link_name, weblink.link_url %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: But then I must add a relationship in the controller? I can't just say: @categories = Category.all and @weblinks = Weblink.all?

Comment: I you've said "has_many :weblinks" in your Category class and "belongs_to :category" in your Weblink, then for a given instance of Category, Category#weblinks either retrieves all weblinks with the correct category_id from the database or returns the weblinks previously retrieved (e.g. if you used ":include => :weblinks" when doing Category.all in the controller, as Victor suggests).